# Intermediate lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

I am doing [Project Euler question 55](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=55) on Lychrel numbers where the aim is to find the number of Lychrel numbers below 10,000 within 50 iterations. I came up with this:

```
revAdd n = (read $ reverse $ show n) + n

lychrel n | length xs == 50 = error "False"
          | ((reverse $ show (revAdd n)) == (show (revAdd n)))  = True
          | otherwise  = (lychrel (revadd n) ) : xs

answer = length [ x | x <- [1..10000] , lychrel x == True]
```

But I don't know how to define `xs` as the list of previous iterations upon `n`, which are when `n` is not a palindrome. How would I do this, and secondly would this work?

Comment: Useless boolean comparison to `True`.  Remember, `something == True` = `something`; `something == False` == `not something`.  I hate it when people do this in *any* language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It becomes much easier if you separate your concerns into distinct steps.

1. Define a function that sums a number and its reverse.
2. Use [`iterate`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Aiterate) to repeat your number, starting from `x`.
3. Use [`take`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Atake) to limit your iteration to 50 steps.
4. Use [`all`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Aall) with a predicate to determine if any of these steps results in a palindrome.

Comment: Duh, of course I meant `any` not `all`.  Basically the same thing, though; De Morgan's Law `any p = or . map p = not . and . map (not . p) = not . all (not . p)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the list of iterations (or just the number of iterations) in as a parameter to `lychrel`, starting with `[]` in the call from `answer` and adding to it in the recursive call in the `otherwise` case. Look up "accumulating parameters" for more general background on this technique.